# Getting rid of Group Policy

Tags: windows-7, windows, group-policy

I am running Windows 7 on a Dell Laptop. I am the only user/administrator. On almost all programs I try to download or run, I am getting an error of "blocked by group policy. Contact system administrator". My user account is the only account that I am able to access right now. It shows I am the administrator if you look deeper into my account information. However, I cannot seem to get access into the administrative account at all! Please help!! Beyond frustrated with this whole Group Policy thing!

Answer (score 0):

If you are the administrator, you can disable the functionality by going to the services console (services.msc) and disable the "Group Policy Client" service.

In any case I should add that if your user account has indeed administrator privileges, that should not be happening in the first place.

Comment: That's what I thought too. I've tried to disable it through the services console & I get the same result. Only this time it says "Access Denied" or "You do not have permission". Is it possible that when I changed the UAC settings I screwed it up? I didn't have this problem before then.

Comment: It's possible, yes. Try disabling UAC and restart the machine to troubleshoot the issue, while the service is disabled.